# Is there documentation for the @Model type in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm customizing my father-in-law's Orchard site and trying to create a .cshtml file to control the display of a Containable content type, but I'm having a bugger of a time finding the data in the @Model field. Is there any documentation on it anywhere?

So far I've found @Model.Slug and @Model.Title. What I'd really like is access to the custom fields on the Content Type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Model object is of a `dynamic` type so it's properties are dynamically added depending on what modules are being used.

If you are using the new 1.1.30 version of Orchard you can use the new Shape Tracing tool which is part of the [Deisgner Tools module](http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools) which can be installed through the modules gallery.  This will add a panel to the bottom of your website page that will allow you to see and navigate through the Model object.

Comment: In addition - the dynamic Model object exposes all named parameters passed at shape creation time, as properties. So eg. if you'd call `@Display(New.MyShape(Prop1: value1, Prop2: value2))` to display MyShape somewhere, you can then access values passed as `Model.Prop1` and `Model.Prop2` inside the shape file (MyShape.cshtml).

Comment: An alternative to the call above would be `@Display(New.MyShape().Prop1(value1).Prop2(value2))`, btw.